# AmE pronunciation of 'cliché' vs 'niche'

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I have noticed that some Americans (not all) pronounce the word 'niche' as 'nitch' (IPA /nɪtʃ/) rather than as 'neesh' (IPA /niːʃ/).

> **niche**
>   Pronunciation: /niːʃ/
>   Pronunciation: /nɪtʃ/
>   ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/niche))

Why do these same people not pronounce '*cliché*' with a "tch" (IPA /tʃ/) sound?

Both words are loanwords from French, but the treatment of the "ch" sound seems to be inconsistent. Is it due to the difference in accentuation?

Also, which groups of people use '*nitch*' as the pronunciation for *niche*?

Is it wrong or can one argue for it?

As a Brit, unsure as to internal American differences in pronunciation, I was wondering if *nitch* is more of a western pronunciation. I have heard that it becomes more like British English as you go East.

Comment: US Midwesterner here - I say "nitch".  (and "clishay")  Go figure! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez As a Brit, unsure as to internal American pronunciational(?) differences, is *nitch* more of a western pronunciation?- I have heard that it becomes for like BrE as you go East. Also, as a matter of interest, (in an ideal world) do you use an accent on *cliché*?

Comment: By the way, this is a subject where you can easily do some research for yourself. Your question is likely to be received better if you include references to dictionaries. The [American Heritage Dictionary entry for "niche"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=niche) has a relevant usage note.

Comment: @sumelic Thanks for the assistance, I'll add some references.

Comment: I made an edit to try to emphasize what I think is the most interesting question here, the inconsistency between "niche" and "cliché." The AHD entry explains a fair amount of what you seem to want to learn about the two pronunciations of "niche," but its entry on "[cliché](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=cliché&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)" does not explain the pronunciation of that word.

Comment: Whoops, I think we were editing at the same time. I made a new edit to try to combine the changes we made. The "OED" is actually a different dictionary from "Oxford Dictionaries." I'd advise removing the "Is it wrong or can one argue for it?" line, since various dictionaries make clear that the "nitch" pronunciation is not wrong and the AHD explains the argument for it.

Comment: Yes I think we were, nevertheless your edit is perfect. I hadn't realise that the two dictionaries were independent, I wonder how they evolved, I'm sure there's a story in there somewhere…

Comment: Hmm, well they're both published by [Oxford University Press](http://global.oup.com/?cc=us), so there is some relation in that sense. But the entries are all different. It's not uncommon for a publisher to have several different lines of dictionaries.

Comment: Well I suppose that is what a university does for a town (six ranges of dictionaries). I noticed I accidentally ignored one of your edits adding in my contextual information, I've added that back in.

Comment: Interesting comment from Garner's Modern American Usage: "niche" is best pronounced /nich/. The pronunciation, predominant in AmE. . . Although the pronunciation /neesh/ is heard among educated speakers, many consider it a pretentious deanglicazation of a word that has been anglicized since the 1700s.

Comment: Yes to the accent on cliché.

Comment: Because they're two different words that have different pronunciations? Consider the British pronunciations of *garage* and *mirage*. These are two French words that were appropriated in the last 200 years. Why don't they rhyme?

Comment: I'm British and was brought up in the 1950s. My parents and most peole I knew pronounced it 'nitch' and I think that 'neesh' has become more common over the last 60 years. By the way @PeterShor 'garaj' and 'miraj' do rhyme where I come from

Comment: @BoldBen that's interesting, I had heard that some Brits pronounced it 'nitch' but had never seen evidence of it. I suppose the same logic applies to you as to the Americans

Comment: Another word of possible interest here is _Vichy_. You might expect from U.S. pronunciation of _niche_ that Americans would tend to pronounce _Vichy_ either "vitchy" (rhyming with "itchy") or "veeshy"; but the only pronunciation that _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) gives for is "vishy" (rhyming with "fishy"). In the United States, I think, a person's choice of how to pronounce _niche_ depends to a large extent on (1) how common the word is in everyday speech in the area (which reinforces the regional pronunciation), and (2) whether the person speaks any French.

Comment: @SvenYargs Of course 'Vichy' (in the context of the Vichy government rather than the mineral water) entered the language after the introduction of radio and talking pictures. It also came into the language to a great extent through radio news and movie newsreels so people heard the standard pronunciation as they became aware of the word. I would expect that this would affect the adoption of the pronunciation.

Comment: These two words are from the french language. Neither is pronounced nor written with any t. Take it from a french native speaker!

Comment: In the US many people use both pronunciations of *niche*, depending on whether they are being formal or informal.  The "frenchy" pronunciation sounds a bit to hoity-toity to many people, when used in normal conversation.

Comment: Regarding “which groups of people … ,” it could perhaps be interesting to see if there is any connection between how someone pronounces “niche” and how they pronounce Friedrich Nietzsche’s last name.  To the extent that it could be argued that one’s pronunciation of a German surname containing several letters not found in “niche” is totally irrelevant, perhaps it could nevertheless be interesting (and even slightly relevant) to see how “niche” is most often pronounced by people who have never heard of Friedrich Nietzsche.

Answer (score 3):

*OED* has for *niche*

> Brit.   /niːʃ/ ,  /nɪtʃ/ , U.S.  /nɪtʃ/ ,  /niʃ/

so both sides of the Atlantic have both pronunciations; but which is more common is reversed.  *OED* also has alternate spellings from the past:

> 16 neece, 16 niece, 16 niech, 16–17 neech, 16–17 nice, 16–18 nich, 16–18 nitch, 16– niche.

Jonathan Swift, 1733:

> If I can but fill my Nitch, I attempt no higher Pitch.

For *cliché*

> /kliʃe/ /ˈkliːʃeɪ/

Apparently no /tʃ/ version

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey IPA _is_ the phonetic transcription. ;-). Interesting alternative spellings listed. I wonder how a 16th-century writer fond of alternative spellings would write, “That's a nice niche, niece”…

Comment: You skipped the meat of the OED entry: *N.E.D. (1907) gives only the pronunciation (nitʃ) /nɪtʃ/ and the pronunciation /niːʃ/ is apparently not recorded before this date. H. Michaelis & D. Jones Phonetic Dict. Eng. Lang. (1913), and all editions of D. Jones Eng. Pronouncing Dict. up to and including the fourteenth edition (1977) give /nɪtʃ/ as the typical pronunciation and /niːʃ/ as an alternative pronunciation. The fifteenth edition (1991) gives /niːʃ/ in British English and /nɪtʃ/ in U.S. English.*

Comment: This answer is great as reference material but does not explain *why* this phenomenon exists.

Comment: @Blad I fear a true answer is likely impossible to find. Some words just end up more Anglicised than others. It could depend on factors like how and from whom people initially learnt the word when it entered the language, where it first became widespread, what French dialect it was borrowed from, etc. As choster’s comment shows, it was initially /nɪtʃ/ everywhere and then (by association with words like _cliché_) started changing to /niːʃ/ at some point; there doesn’t seem to be any evidence extant as to why it got /tʃ/ in the first place when _cliché_ didn’t.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That might be true, perhaps I'll never get a true answer. If you want to expand on that I'll give you the bounty if you want.

Answer (score 0):

The online etymology dictionary gives this origin for **niche**

> 1610s, "shallow recess in a wall," from French niche "recess (for a dog), kennel" (14c.), perhaps from Italian nicchia "niche, nook," from nicchio "seashell," said by Klein and Barnhart to be probably from Latin mitulus "mussel," but the change of -m- to -n- is not explained. Watkins suggests that the word is from an Old French noun derived from nichier "to nestle, nest, build a nest," via Gallo-Roman *nidicare from Latin nidus "nest;" but that has difficulties, too. Figurative sense is first recorded 1725. Biological use dates from 1927.

It gives this origin for **cliche**

> 1825, "electrotype, stereotype," from French cliché, a technical word in printer's jargon for "stereotype block," noun use of past participle of clicher "to click" (18c.), supposedly echoic of the sound of a mold striking molten metal. Figurative extension to "trite phrase, worn-out expression" is first attested 1888, following the course of stereotype. Related: Cliched (1928).

The pronunciation difference may be due to niche entering the language earlier. It is interesting that cliche was a *printing* term. Perhaps that encouraged the use of the written accent, which in turn affected pronunciation, since the word was presumably used most often by printers.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at youglish site. Most Americans will pronounce niche as 'nitch' and only a few of them as 'niche'. It doesn't look like it has something to do with the East/West location or the level of education.

http://youglish.com/search/niche/us